# Subversion revert issue version 1.7.9

Tags: svn, branch

Is it possible to start a branch from a past date? I want to start a new branch from 6 months back.

Also I want to merge that branch with one existing branch. Any neat way to do it?

Comment: thanks for adding the tag Emmanuel.

Answer (score 1):

To start a branch from a past date, just make your copy from the revision you want to start with.

```
svn cp <SOURCE_URL>@BRANCH_REVISION -BRANCH_REVISION <BRANCH_URL>
```

Where `BRANCH_REVISION` is the revision number in the past that you want to start the branch from. See [Peg and Operative Revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) in the SVN Manual.

From that point, it acts like any other branch or copy.